# SFMCSdk ios crash react native

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, mobilepush-ios, react-native-marketingcloudsdk

Trying to integrate `react-native 0.68` with  `"react-native-marketingcloudsdk": "^8.0.0"`

The app crashed with the below error.
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model'`

In the documentation, it's showing as common exceptions.
`Common Exceptions When latest MarketingCloudSDK.bundle not added in the application`.

But I don't know how to add the bundle.

https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/trouble/trouble-marketingCloudSDK-bundle-exception.html

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I have edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding MarketingCloudSDK.bundle to `Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources` from the pod.